# Limiting "in-flight" asynchronous calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, q

I have a number of async calls being made in JavaScript. I would like to ensure that only a single async call is in flight at any one time. How can I achieve this?

Does the Q library expose something relevant to this?

Comment: Make each call in the callback function of the previous one.

Comment: can you explain why?   It would seem the only way to actively prevent a second async call from being in-flight would be to "busy loop" until the first one is finished, and that's not good...    [or per Barmar, just arrange your code so that they're launched in turn from the previous call's callback]

Comment: @Alnitak Separate question for myself then I guess. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to only have one asynchronous call in flight at once? It sounds like you're converting them to synchronous calls. 

You can use AMD loading to ensure all dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: async.series() from async.js

Comment: The reason I am considering this approach is to avoid "overloading" the event loop. I want to retain UI responsiveness whilst a lot of activity is going on behind the scenes. Currently the "unresponsive script" dialog is appearing in Firefox due to the load on the event loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to retain all calls or discard any calls made while one is in-flight.

If you want to retain all calls, you shouldn't make the Ajax calls directly, but rather put them in a queue. The queue abstraction would then be responsible for making the Ajax calls, using a lock variable to check if one is already in-flight. When an Ajax call is received or timed out, it can trigger the queue to check for any pending calls so the next one can be fired off.

If you want to discard calls made while one is in-flight, a simple lock mechanism would do. For any call, just check if the lock is true and if not, fire the request and set the lock to true. If the lock is true, do nothing (discard it). Clear the lock when the call is received or times out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Q user, but Q is essentially a library implementing promises, so you can ensure this by chaining a series of .then clauses together, each one containing one call, or launching the next call from the .done operation of the previous AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

What i can think of is using a functions queue to process ajax functions based on the result of jQuery.active which counts the active ashync calls.

So when calling an ajax function check for the active ajax running, if it is 1 then add your function to the queue, other wise execute it.

You can then use the ajaxStop function to trigger any remaining function to be called within the queue, call the function and remove it from queue.

In this way you will ensure that a single ajax call runs. This is just some brainstorming, I haven't tested the exact behavior but this approach might help.